# Probability distribution of $aX + b$, where a and b are integers and $X$ is a uniform variable

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, random-variable

My textbook has the following introductory example about functions of random variables:

> Suppose that $X$ is a random continuous variable with a uniform distribution over the interval $(0,1)$. Determine the distribution of $Y = aX + b$, where $a$ and $b$ are non-zero integers.

The solution provided in the textbook comes with no explanation and it differs from what I ended up with. What's the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please read the self-study tag and its wiki and edit your question to include information about what you have tried, your thought process, and where you are stuck.

Comment: I wanted to post every step I did but I can't format the text well and it looks ugly and unreadable.

Comment: A tutorial on math formatting can be found here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: In accordance with the `self-study` guidelines, please show your attempt. If it's ugly but understandable, someone will probably help format it for you but I strongly encourage you to read user777's link above.

Comment: You might benefit from considering direct calculation - start with $F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)$, substituting $aX+b$ for $Y$ and simplifying to get an expression for $F_Y(y)$ in terms of $F_X$, then obtaining $f_Y$ from the resulting expression for $F_Y$.

Answer (score 3):

For $t \in (b, a + b)$ and $a > 0$ we have
\begin{align}
P(aX + b \leq t) &= P \left ( X \leq \frac{t - b}{a} \right ) \\
&= \frac{t - b}{a} .
\end{align}
When $a < 0$
\begin{align}
P(aX + b \leq t) &= P \left ( X \geq\frac{t - b}{a} \right ) \\
&= 1 -  P \left ( X < \frac{t - b}{a} \right ) \\
&= 1 - \frac{t - b}{a} 
\end{align}
which is a uniform distribution function in either case.

Comment: The assertion that $\displaystyle P(aX + b \leq t) = P \left ( X \leq \frac{t - b}{a} \right )$ is incorrect when $a < 0$.

Comment: The opening sentence is correct when $a > 0$ but not when $a < 0$.

Comment: If we're being pedantic then pretend the numbers are in the other order.  The interpretation of something like $(0, -1)$ should be obvious.

Comment: You are writing an answer for the benefit of someone who is having difficulty understanding what is alleged to be a solved example in a book that provides little explanation of the solution. I fail to see how your answer is any improvement.

Comment: I don't understand how you calculated the probability at all. Doesn't the uniform distribution state that for $X$ in $(a,b)$  $P(X <= x) = (x-a)/(b-a)$ ?

Comment: If you apply that formula for the uniform distribution function for appropriate values of $a$ and $b$ then you can follow the argument.  We use it first for a random variable whose distribution is uniform$(0, 1)$, and then see that the distribution function of $aX + b$ is that of a uniform distribution with bounds $b$ and $b + a$.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can do this via [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables).

First, find the inverse mapping of $g(X)=aX+b$, $g^{-1}(Y)=(Y-b)/a$.

The density of $Y$ is, in general, given by
$$
f_Y(x)=f_X(g^{-1}(x))|g^{-1'}(x)|
$$
Now, $g^{-1'}(x)=1/|a|$. As $f_X\equiv1$, we obtain
$$
f_Y(x)=1/|a|,
$$
a uniform density (on $[a,b]$).

Upon taking the derivative in the answer of @dsaxton, we see that the solutions agree.